# How to pass View Param to View Model DataSource in Kendo Mobile?

Tags: mobile, kendo-ui, param

What is the correct way to pass a view variable from the URL to a View Model to filter the result?

For example:

```
dataSource: new kendo.DataSource( { 
    transport: {
        read: {
           url: 'http://api.endpoint.com/resource',
        }
        parameterMap: function(options,type) {
            if (type === 'read') {
                return {
                   FormID: view.params.FormID
                };
            }
        }

});
```

In the example above, there's a parameter in the URL called "FormID" and I would like to pass that value right to the parameterMap function. There is no "view" object, so I'm just putting that as an example.

I tried hooking into to the "data-show" and "data-init" functions to set this value to use, but the datasource fetches the data before these functions run.

Thanks

Comment: Any progress here?  I'm looking to do the same thing but would rather just tack it on to the end of the url so it's something like 'http://api.endpoint.com/resource/123'

Comment: @2GDave sounds like you want to make transport.read a function so you can compose the url; I don't understand where the value to append to the url is supposed to come from though

Comment: Right, I want to use a variable to construct the api endpoint URL and then set the datasource to the data returned.  The value will be passed in from the original list.  In this case I have a list of RSS Feeds and when you click on a feed it will load up the feed items for that feed.

Comment: Here's the template for the list of feeds:

<div id="feedsView" data-role="view" data-title="PNR Feeds" data-model="app.pnrfeedsService.viewModel">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset"
        data-bind="source: pnrfeedsDataSource"
        data-template="pnr-feeds-template"></ul>
</div>

<script id="pnr-feeds-template" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
    <div class="w-item-template">
        <a href="feeditemsView?FeedID=${FeedID}" data-role="listview-link"><h4 class="w-date">${FeedName}</h4></a>
    </div>
</script>

Answer (score 2):

The configuration option [`options.transport.read`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.read) can be a function, so you can compose the url there:

```
dataSource: new kendo.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: function (options) {
            // get the id from wherever it is stored (e.g. your list view)
            var resourceId = getResourceId(); 

            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://api.endpoint.com/resource/' + resourceId,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function (result) {
                    options.success(result);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    options.error(result);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

To connect this with your list view, you could use the listview's [change event](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/listview#events-change):

```
data-bind="source: pnrfeedsDataSource, events: { change: onListViewChange }"
```

then in `viewModel.onListViewChange` you could set the appropriate resource id for the item that was clicked on:

```
// the view model you bind the list view to
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    // ..., your other properties
    onListViewChange: function (e) {
        var element = e.sender.select(); // clicked list element
        var uid = $(element).data("uid");
        var dataItem = this.dataSource.getByUid(uid);

        // assuming your data item in the data source has the id 
        // in dataItem.ResourceId
        this._selectedResource = dataItem.ResourceId; 
    }
});
```

Then `getResourceId()` could get it from `viewModel._selectedResource` (or it could be a getter on the viewModel itself). I'm not sure how all of this is structured in your code, so it's difficult to give more advice; maybe you could add a link to jsfiddle for illustration.

Comment: So what would getResourceId() look like?  Would that function then have access to the view so I could get a view parms?  I think this is what I'm looking for, but now I'm unsure of getting the resourceId into this function.  Any thoughts?

Comment: see edit (if this doesn't work, it would help to know more about how this is structured, e.g. how the DS is related to the view model)

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to Kendo and the mobile UI stuff, so the help is much appreciated.  I'll give it a shot and let you know how it goes.

Comment: As I said in the comment below, thanks again to both of you for the effort!  I've got it up and working and now I'm on to jaydata to take care of it a little more too.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a "global" variable or a field in the viewmodel for that purpose. Something like

```
var vm = kendo.observable({
   FormID: null, 
   dataSource: new kendo.DataSource( { 
   transport: {
    read: {
       url: 'http://api.endpoint.com/resource',
    }
    parameterMap: function(options,type) {
        if (type === 'read') {
            return {
               FormID: vm.FormID
            };
        }
    }
  })
});

function viewShow(e) {
    vm.set("FormID", e.view.params.FormID);
    // at this point it is usually a good idea to invoke the datasource read() method.
    vm.dataSource.read();
}
```

The datasource will fetch the data before the view show event if a widget is bound to it. You can work around this problem by setting the widget `autoBind` configuration option to `false` - all data-bound Kendo UI widgets support it.

Comment: In this example how would "resource" know what "FormID" was if the resource is an api endpoint?  Does that get passed as some sort of request parameter?

Comment: The formID is passed as a query string parameter to the view hosting the widget bound to the datasource in question. The viewShow function is a callback bound to the view show event, like @AndreLiem suggested.

More info on view parameters: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/mobile/view#view-parameters

Comment: Thanks so much for the help from you guys.  If I could have split the 50 bounty between both I would but I couldn't so I awarded it based on AUTOBIND as related to the viewShow, as that was partly the key for me as I wasn't getting the viewparm as it was binding too early.  Thanks again!